# Hierarchical Product Category plugin for Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have my product categories setup in a hierarchical structure and I need a plugin to display them in a menu or page where I can click through each category to see the child categories, looking for a plugin that achieves this if anyone know of one, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Default you will get an option in widgets to display categories in hierarchy but it's not on click

[image]

There is one more filter plugin which list Parent & child categories. The child categories will be displayed on click - https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/

Comment: Good stuff, I'd forgotten about woof, thanks